# Checking if a client is trying to connect?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

In order to check if a message is pending I can use `Socket.Available`, but what should I do in order to check if a client is trying to connect to my server before calling `Socket.Accept`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After some time I found a solution. Just set the `Socket.Blocking` property to `false`. Then the `Socket.Accept` function is going to check if there is a pending connection, if there is a pending connection it is going to accept this connection, if not a `SocketException` is thrown with `SocketException.ErrorCode` equal to "10035". If this type of exception is thrown with the error code "10035", I will check if I want to exit, if yes I would exit, if not I will recall the `Socket.Accept` function and repeat the procedure.

Note: same way can be used calling other blocking methods with actually blocking the thread execution.

Sources:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.blocking(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This amounts to busy spinning and drives a CPU to 100%. You'll need to add a delay. This delay now causes a delay when accepting connections, it limits the number of connections per second accepted severely (from 100k to maybe 100 at 10ms delay), it's still inefficient and the code is more awkward. Also note that code like this is what drains your mobile device battery. I recommend just closing the socket.

Comment: Another concern is that exceptions are very expensive (0.1ms) so this will actually amount to a meaningful amount of CPU time. Also, you can no longer set the debugger to break on all exceptions which is a great default setting. Debug output will be polluted.

Answer (score 3):

TCP does not provide messages so you can't check for messages under any circumstances. You can see how many bytes are *at least* available but it might not be a message and it could be multiple messages. Also, `Available` might be `0` when 1ns later data arrives. So the test buys you nothing.

You don't need to check for data or for connections ever.

Just run an accept loop:

```
while (true) {
 RunConnectionAsync(socket.Accept());
}
```

The same for reading: Have a read request outstanding at all times when data might be coming. The `Read` will wait until data has arrived.

Do. Or do not. There is no try. (In this case: Always do.)

Comment: I'm doing this on an external thread, so it is asynchronous, but I don't want the thread to be blocked in order be able to end it peacefully.

Comment: The common way to end socket calls "peacefully" is by closing the socket. There is no cleaner way. If you don't like that this *forces* a polling solution which is quite ugly. The closing solution is the cleaner way.

Comment: Someone requested a better API for cancelling socket operations on Github, fyi: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5749

Comment: "I don't want the thread to be blocked" - how about `AcceptAsync` / `BeginAccept`?

Comment: @codran that works, too, but in case he wants to end the operation he still needs to cancel the IOs. That requires Close(). So it's really the same thing.

Comment: Looks like I just found a cleaner way @usr :D